# Nootropics for epileptics

Tags: medications, amphetamine, epilepsy, nootropic-smart-drugs

***Hello guys!***

**I'm epileptic and last months I have some problems with my attention and my memory**. Another problem is, I'm from Russia and we don't have here good pills or really qualified doctors and medication service. I mean we have no chargeable insurance, you need to pay for all. And if you can't, there are free service, worse than which only service in Africa... Probably.

**So, I wanna to start using nootropics. But almost every medication has notice, that it can gives side effects for my disease**.

**Actually, I would like to use "Adderal", 'cause of amphetamine inside 'cause it steals all your attention whatever you do**. And this would really helpful for me. **But we don't have it here free for sale** (to be honest, ***there is absolutely no drug here as I think***, only strange online pharmacies sells it).

So, **I wanna combine some local nootropics with amphetamine** if it would possible.

There are 4 questions:

**Is it possible?**

**Will it give the same effect as Adderall?**

**What is the probability that nootropics give side effects on epilepsy?**

**How will the probability increase if I mix nootropics with amphetamine?**

P.S. **I use "Topiramate" for now** (the best medication for me).

Before I used "Lamotrigine" (worse) and before that I used "Depakine chrono" ("Valproic acid" is active substance as I know, that was the worst and the most expensive), which didn't help me at all.

Comment: Amphetamines require a prescription in most countries and are frequently drugs of abuse so tightly controlled. Obtaining them without a doctor's prescription will be difficult.

Comment: @CareyGregory yeah, I understand that